# how can I use git log to use parent #1 to generate the patch

Tags: git

I can see the left hand lane of my git history like this:

```
git log origin/master --pretty=oneline --first-parent --decorate=no
```

the way my project is set-up, those are the only important changes most of the time.

However, when searching the patches with `-G`, I would like to search the difference between the commit, and its parent #1, so that every change that has happened in the project is covered by the search.

```
git log origin/master --pretty=oneline --first-parent --decorate=no -G keyword
```

The reason is that the tree looks like this

[image]

and I want to consider that whole trapezoid as a single action for some purposes.  In the list generated by the above `git log`, it is shown as a single command, but I have no way of then searching the history in that format so that I can tell immediately in which git group that happened.

It would also be great if whatever options can do this could work for gitk so that when I go

```
gitk origin/master --first-parent
```

and make it appear as a single commit

[image]

I could click on it and see the diff generated by

```
git diff [merge commit]:[merge commit]^
```

The git documentation mentioned environment variables `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` and `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` that sound like they might be what I am looking for, but I can't really find any examples.

Comment: I have not tried this, but `git log --first-parent -m -G ...` *should* cause the searching you'd like. Unfortunately `gitk` runs its own independent `git rev-list` command initially, and won't let you use this kind of trick at all. It probably should be modified to add a checkbox or radio buttons for merge commits, to pick which parent to diff when sitting on it to view it.

Comment: `       -m
           This flag makes the merge commits show the full diff like regular commits; for each merge parent, a separate log entry and diff is generated. An exception is that only diff against the first parent is shown when --first-parent option
           is given; in that case, the output represents the changes the merge brought into the then-current branch.`
- it was right there! thanks a lot.  I wish you answered as an answer so I could upvote and/or accept

Comment: (i tried it; it works)

Comment: @Alex028502 since you've found a working solution, it would be much appreciated by future readers if you post it as an answer yourself. You can also accept that answer, and in fact you're encouraged to do so whenever you honestly think it's the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-m` flag to the command you already have:

```
git log -m --pretty=oneline --first-parent --decorate=no -G keyword origin/master
```

(I moved the starting point to the end of the options, although for Git, you can put it wherever you like as long as it is not after a double hyphen `--`).

The `-m` option—think of it as short for *merge*—makes `git log` treat a merge commit as a series of multiple separate commits, each with the same child commit but each with a single parent.  When combining this with `--first-parent`, it treats the merge commit as if it were just an ordinary non-merge commit with the first parent as its only parent.  In either case, you do get a diff, which `-G` can then search.

(Unfortunately, this does not work with `gitk`, which doesn't use `git log` directly.  It runs its own `git rev-list` internally and then does everything else on its own.)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option, with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/755fb09163ec71b784b1bd9db5cb73de7a01d078/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> and friends learned `--dd` that is a shorthand for `--diff-merges=first-parent -p`.

See [commit 7c446ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c446ac7903555356d66e24dca5e370f0e1158bc), [commit c8e5cb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8e5cb065802e96c5aa5dd25936d9780c5734182), [commit be3820c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be3820c60cc82e0ded1d3f3dcc19fbd59ce56aa2) (09 Oct 2023) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 755fb09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/755fb09163ec71b784b1bd9db5cb73de7a01d078), 23 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff-merges`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8e5cb065802e96c5aa5dd25936d9780c5734182): introduce '`--dd`' option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> This option provides a shortcut to request diff with respect to first parent for any kind of commit, universally.
> It's implemented as pure synonym for "`--diff-merges=first-parent --patch`".
>
> Gives user quick and universal way to see what changes, exactly, were brought to a branch by merges as well as by regular commits.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c8e5cb065802e96c5aa5dd25936d9780c5734182/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L53-L57):

> ### `--dd`
>
> Produce diff with respect to first parent for both merge and
> regular commits.
> Shortcut for '--diff-merges=first-parent -p'.

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c8e5cb065802e96c5aa5dd25936d9780c5734182/Documentation/git-log.txt#L123):

> `-m`, `-c`, `--cc`, and `--dd` options) is explicitly given, merge commits